# Custom sorting param on Pageable

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

Using Spring Data Rest I can tweak the representation by using projections or even putting a DTO in the middle but ... Is it possible to introduce an indirection in the sorting param using Pageable?

I am thinking how far can go into decoupling the exposed API rest from the database model entity field names while using Spring Data Rest.

Comment: with `?sort=myProperty,desc` [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting.sorting)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explain myself. This is about having an immutable API even when POJO field names change so the client does not has to change their URLs in case of changes in the entity. So this is precisely How to NOT use myProperty in the sort param.

Comment: See my updated answer..

Comment: What about posting some code then? What does your repository look like now. Are you using the QueryDsl bindings to dynamically sort and filter?

Comment: Simple pagingAndSorting repository with dynamic finders accepting a Pageable param. Point is I want to tweak the Sort object in the Pageable so it does not assume the sort param as an entity field but put some indirection there. I am trying to act at PageableResolver level but maybe there is a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

To set default sort order in the paged `findAll` method of your repository, you can use the following trick:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Override
    default Page<Listing> findAll(Pageable p) {
        if (p.getSort() == null) {

            // Default sort order
            return findAllBy(new PageRequest(p.getPageNumber(), p.getPageSize(), Sort.Direction.DESC, "myProperty"));
        }
        return findAllBy(p);
    }

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    Page<Listing> findAllBy(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for because I am not considering only the default sorting ... but it is an interesting approach I haven't think about. Thanks! I am trying to create a mechanism to replace sorting param using a mapping defined by each controller or repository.